# Simple Poisson problem

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

I wanted to ensure that I solve the following problem correctly:
There is a door to the building and I do not have a key. On average, every 5 minutes a person enters or exits the building (i.e., eventually opening the door). What is probability that I will enter the door within 3 minutes.

Solution:
1. Lambda: on average 0.6 people entering/exiting the building in 3 minutes

2. The probability to enter the building in 3 minutes is the probability 1-the probability that no one enters / exits the building.
3. The probability that no one enters / exits the building: P(X=0) = e^-0.6 = 0.55
4. Probability to enter the building within 3 minutes is 1-0.55 = 0.45

Thanks!

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: You probably mean "exits". The word "exists" was confusing me and  somehow the movie "matrix" came into my mind.

Comment: Yes, fixed :) But the solution is correct, you think ?

Comment: It would seem that you need more information about the PDF of the "average" entry time.  If the PDF was inside of an approximate delta function at every 5 minutes (suitable limit) then that problem is answered in a AMM problem; your chance of getting there for some lapse time.  I don't remember the exact date/number for the problem.  If it was uniformly distributed then you would have a different problem.  For instance, if the arrival of the neighbors was ever 4min and 6min then the average would be 5 min but your expectation would probably be skewed.

Answer (score -1):

Since average number of people who enter or exit in 5min is 1 we can conclude probability that at least one person enters or exits in 1min is 0.2. So, probability that at least one person does it in 3min is =1-(1-0.2)^3=0.488
I tried this in matlab simulations and its checks.

Comment: "Since average number of people who enter or exit in 5min is 1 we can conclude probability that at least one person enters or exits in 1min is 0.2".  *FALSE*

Comment: Can you elaborate, and correct my mistakes?